# Font not working on other some PCs and iPhone?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My website font is `font-family: Century Gothic;`.

On my PC it works correctly but on other PCs it is changed.

It also doesn't work on the iPhone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because those PCs and the iPhone do not have the font installed.

If you want to ensure that your font works on as many computers as possible, you should consider using `@font-face`.

The basic CSS syntax is

```
@font-face{
    font-family: CenturyGothic;
    src: url('CenturyGothic.otf');
}
```

And then

```
font-family: CenturyGothic, serif;  /* Whatever others you want to add */
```

Six Revisions has a good overview: http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/

FontSquirrel will generate the code for you: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

**It should be noted** that unless the font is a non-commercial font, you will need a license to use it with `@font-face`.  That is, you will need to purchase the font and maybe even purchase the right to distribute it.

(Thanks to [@bookcasey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052923/bookcasey) for highlighting the need to add this info)

A good resource for info on licensing is http://blog.themeforest.net/general/font-licensing-for-the-web/

Having said that, there are thousands of freely available fonts - including dozens on the FontSquirrel site - where no licensing is necessary.

Comment: He almost certainly does not have a license to embed that font on his website.

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted if I provide incorrect information.  But please help me and those viewing this post/answer know what is wrong with the info provided.  Leave a comment explaining the downvote!

Comment: @bookcasey You are probably right. The two links I posted speak to the licensing issue.

Comment: Your example suggests he should upload Century Gothic to the FontSquirrel generator, and as he probably does not have a license to embed that font, it is illegal for him to embed it. I will remove the down vote, and even up vote if you make this clear in your answer.

Comment: @bookcasey Thanks for clarification.  I edited the post to make it more explicit.

Comment: But on IPhone it is not installed